# How can I list all cards I am watching in Trello?

Tags: trello

How could I list all watched cards (or as a further refinement all watched cards I am not working on)?

I couldn't see anything immediately on the pages regarding [watching](https://help.trello.com/article/799-watching-cards-lists-and-boards), [filtering](https://help.trello.com/article/787-filtering-cards-on-a-board) or [searching](https://help.trello.com/article/808-searching-for-cards-all-boards).